# WPF infragistics unbound column Filter not accessible

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics, wpf-4.0, xamgrid

I have to use XamGrid (version 12.2) with unbound column. I managed to add unbound column to display data but not able to apply any filter. Is there anything needed to be done in Xaml to have filter accessible for unbound column. I am using Filter Menu option to have excel like filter enabled.

[image]

Following is xaml sample

```
<ig:XamGrid Name="xamGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <ig:XamGrid.FilteringSettings>
                <ig:FilteringSettings AllowFiltering="FilterMenu"  FilteringScope="ColumnLayout">
                </ig:FilteringSettings>
            </ig:XamGrid.FilteringSettings>
            <ig:XamGrid.Columns>
                <ig:UnboundColumn Key="myfield" HeaderText="My Field" 
                          ValueConverter="{StaticResource fieldConverter}" 
                          ValueConverterParameter=""
                          IsFilterable="True">
                    <ig:UnboundColumn.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ig:UnboundColumn.ItemTemplate>
                </ig:UnboundColumn>
            </ig:XamGrid.Columns>
        </ig:XamGrid>
```

Also raised in Infragistics forum : http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/62034/413183.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, they are not providing in build suport for filtering.
http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/xamGrid_Unbound_Column.html

You have to implement custom filtering by referring to the below documentation
http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/xamGrid_Create_a_Custom_Filter.html

Better post your queries in Infragistics forum. (Refer below)
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/default.aspx

Comment: These are Silverlight links, I have issue in WPF.

Comment: Find the links for WPF http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/xamGrid_Unbound_Column.html and for custom filtering http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/xamGrid_Create_a_Custom_Filter.html

Comment: By default the IsFilterable and IsSummable properties are set to False on an unbound column. This is because custom filters and summaries must be written for unbound columns. To enable filtering and summaries on an unbound column, you must set the column’s IsFilterable and IsSummable properties to True and write a custom filter or summary. For more information see the Create a Custom Filter and Create a Custom Summary topics.

Comment: As mentioned in question, I have enabled IsFilterable.. I have run through all options mentioned in Infragistics portal.

Comment: you should ask in infragistics forum. Based on the documentation they are not providing excel like filtering support for unbound columns. you should write custom filtering logic.